# Access ParserRules in Xtext 2.11

Tags: xtext

With the new Xtext 2.11 version, I could set the EntryRule of a XtextResource.
However, I am not able to figure out how to pass the expected ParserRule.

Consider this code

```
    Injector injector = new MydslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
    XtextResourceSet resourceSet = injector.getInstance(XtextResourceSet.class);
    Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("dummy:/test.dsl"));
    XtextResource xres = (XtextResource) resource;
    xres.setEntryPoint(???);
```

It must be somehow similar like in this [testcase](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/blob/0745d5a43d70b2a18b9fe828afbef564fcd06782/org.eclipse.xtext.tests/src/org/eclipse/xtext/resource/SetEntryPointOnXtextResourceTest.xtend), but there seems to be some magic behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xtext creates a Java Class `YourDslGrammarAccess` to gives programmatic access to the grammar. Thus something like the following should work

```
MyDslGrammarAccess ga = injector.getInstance(MyDslGrammarAccess.class);
xres.setEntryPoint(ga.getGreetingRule());
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to specify this EntryPoint in the ParseHelper?

Comment: No. please feel free to file a enhancement request for that in github.com/eclipse/xtext-core. you might simply subclass parsehelper and adapt it accordingly as workaround