# Xtext Parse text using another parser rule than the top one

Tags: java, parsing, xtext, xtend

For testing purposes, I would like to parse a stand-alone expression in my Xtext language.

In my tests, I can parse a complete model using a `ParseHelper<Model>`, e.g.,

```
val model = parseHelper.parse('''function { 1 + 2 }''')
```

Is it possible to parse a stand-alone expression in a similar way? I have tried injecting a `ParseHelper<Expression>` and writing

```
val expr = parseHelper.parse('''1 + 2''')
```

but this returns `null` for some reason.

---

The examples above are based on the following dummy grammar.

```
Model:
    functions+=Function*
;

Function:
    'function' '{' Expression '}'
;

Expression:
      Addition
;
Addition returns Expression:
    Literal (=>({Addition.left=current} '+') right=Literal)*
;
Literal returns Expression:
    INT
;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629743/access-parserrules-in-xtext-2-11
so you might do the parse for test manually. Inject `Provider<ResourceSet> rsp`, ask rsp for resourceset, in resourceset createResource with dummy.mydsl uri, on resource call setEntryRule, call resource.load with string input stream, inspect resource.contents.get(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `IParser` directly. To parse one rule you can do the following:

```js
@Inject IParser parser  // inject the parser
@Inject <Your-Lang-Name-Here>GrammarAccess grammar  // inject your IGrammarAccess

@Test
def void testPartialParse() {
    val expression = '''1 + 2'''
    val IParseResult result = parser.parse(grammar.expressionRule, new StringReader(expression)) // partial parsing here
    assertNotNull(result.rootASTElement)  // rootASTElement should be your Addition
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the work for me. This should be added to the official documentation.